# Exception Load Errors, for files that exist (even in multiple places?)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rvm

I am finding these errors (via debug) and don't understand why I'm getting them.   I'm not sure if I have duplicate files for a reason either.  I'm using .rvm and it has a gems directory with a ruby directory inside of it, but there is also .rvm/rubies/ruby-'version' directory.  I was trying to find some info about the ruby and gem folder structure but so far haven't had much luck.

In other words maybe it's possible I have multiple versions of Ruby or something isn't right?

**Example rubygems.rb**

```
Exception `LoadError' at /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1346 - cannot load such file -- rubygems
defaults/operating_system

**Yet I did a find the file** 
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/plugin/installer/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/plugin/installer/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.12/bundler/lib/bundler/plugin/installer/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.12/bundler/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.12/lib/rubygems.rb
vagrant@vagrant:/home$
```

**Here is one for kernel_require.rb**

```
Exception `LoadError' at /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load
such file -- sinatra
```

Yet Sinatra was running

**here are the kernel_requires**

```
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
./vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.12/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
```

Comment: Yes, rvm is designed for managing multiple ruby versions.  My guess is that there is an installed version of ruby that's not being managed by rvm.  I would check the path.

Comment: Also how are you starting your app?  If your using bundler, then pinning your gem versions in the Gemfile is good practice.  Then always invoke your app prefaced with 'bundle exec'

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought there was another Ruby -v not being managed however I went through the RVM structure and see no discrepancies.

Anyone interested in seeing the directory structure (it wasn't on RVM site), I found it [here](http://xahlee.info/ruby/ruby_rvm_dir_structure.html).

It then came down to my load errors.  I found a post in Ruby trunk issues that said load error, no file found for rubygems.rb was normal, if you are running debug.  I believe it is looking at outside sources of rubygems?.

The last issue was syntax errors for /forwardable/impl.rb.  This was because, again debug was set.  Now I'm not entirely sure what the message means, but the line referenced, 6, is 'resue SyntaxError'.

So I learned a bit more using RVM , gems and some on bundler.  Side note, I was able to use bundle exec on the Sinatra app.